# Apriltag opencv raspberry pi, not working?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero, apriltags

I am using a raspberry Pi Zero W, and a camera module 3 (wide).
I am trying to make a code that detects if an apriltag is on the frame.

I get this error:

```
(python3:649): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:57:03.714: gst_element_post_message: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
Illegal instruction.
```

When I run this code:

````
import cv2
import time
import apriltag

print(cv2.__version__)
dispW = 1280
dispH = 720

cam = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, dispW)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, dispH)

detections = apriltag.Detector()

while True:
stat, frame = cam.read()
         print(time.time())
         if cv2.waitKey(50) == ord('q'):
                    break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````

Comment: Does this help? options = apriltag.DetectorOptions(families="tag36h11")
detector = apriltag.Detector(options)